# Windows - Ruby installation not working properly?

Tags: ruby, windows

I'm running windows server 2016, and upon reinstalling ruby, anything related to gems is not working. Even just typing `gem -v` gives the following error:

```
1: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- ubygems (LoadError)
```

Has anyone encountered this before? I have tried reinstalling ruby. I have tried different versions of ruby and the error persists.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at the file `C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb` on line 54.  The error message says the letter 'r' is missing from the name `rubygems` in the `require` statement.  Did you (or somebody else) inadvertently edit it?

Comment: It might be a version mixup. Until recently, there indeed *was* a file named `ubygems.rb` in the RubyGems `lib` directory. It is a relic from long ago, when RubyGems was not automatically `required` by Ruby. The maintainers of RubyGems thought it would look nicer to write `ruby -rubygems` instead of `ruby -r rubygems`. Similar to how there is a library called `un.rb` in Ruby's stdlib which you can load using `ruby -run`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually rebooted the server and that fixed the issue. I'm guessing an old installation file was cached.